# Selection of a folder path with C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, file, openfiledialog

I have a WPF application in which i have this method:

```
 public static string getFile(List<string> extensions)
 {
     Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
     string ext = "files (", filter = "";
     foreach (string s in extensions)
     {
        ext += s + ",";
        filter += "*." + s + ";";
     }
     ext += ")";
     dlg.Filter =ext+"|"+ filter;
     Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
     if (result == true)
     {
        return dlg.FileName;
     }
     else return null;
  }
```

I need to add another simple method which  returns a folder path in which i will save new file.

1. How can i  do this?
2. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is what you need. From **MSDN** link:

```
// Configure save file dialog box
Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
dlg.DefaultExt = ".text"; // Default file extension
dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; // Filter files by extension 

// Show save file dialog box
Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

// Process save file dialog box results 
if (result == true)
{
    // Save document 
    string filename = dlg.FileName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest having a look at the free [Ookii Dialogs for WPF](http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/). I've used it on commercial projects in the past and it's always worked really well. Native support for WPF obviously but also has a lot of options for customization and provides more consistency across different versions of Windows.